# How to implement a Properties window style control/system in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

So what I am trying to do is to have a set UI with certain controls, and I want to have some class instance to fill in the values.

For instance:

Classes that can populate the UI:

```
Sharpen, Blur, Smear, ... : FilterBase
```

So whenever the user creates an instances of the above classes, I want to automatically fetch the values based on the UI controls, by using the class instance.

The UI has items like:

```
.Name (TextBox)
.Amount (NumericUpDown)
.Decay (NumericUpDown)
```

So if the current instance is `s = new Sharpen()`, I want to get s.Name to fill out UI.Name.

How do I do this in the best possible way? Elegancy, clarity, performance wise, etc.

I am gonna use reflection, but how do I store the instance of the object (Sharpen, ...) and be type safe? Should I use an `System.Object` instead? Or T?

```
public partial class ParamsUI
{
    T CurrentFilter (?)
    ...
}
```

Also if I use T, how will I know what to cast it to?

Is there a better way?

Comment: What UI framework?  This is trivial in WPF - tougher in Windows Forms, for example...

Comment: Sorry it was Winforms. Btw how easy it is in WPF?

Comment: How easy is it in WPF?  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />, that's how easy **grin**.  That said, you can do a similar thing in Windows Forms: it's a bit less flexible, but should suffice for simple text and numeric controls and values.

Comment: When you say, Binding Name, how does it work? I mean do you supply the class name to populate?

Comment: @itowlson: I was thinking more of using DataTemplates, and just making a view per class.  You can then just feed the class strait in, and it does everything for you...  WPF makes this sort of thing much easier, IMO.

Comment: Joan: Why not just use the PropertyGridControl in Windows Forms?

Comment: 600 characters isn't enough room to explain how WPF data binding works, but basically WPF will look for a "binding source" object (which in your case would be specified at the form level as the DataContext property), and will then find its Name property using dependency properties, reflection or whatever, and set up a binding connection between the TextBox's Text property and the source's Name property.  You don't need to supply the class name.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx for more info.

Comment: Reed: good point about using data templates to customise the display per class -- hadn't realised that was what Joan was after.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @Reed. I can't use PropertyGridControl, because the preset UIs I need to use has all sorts of controls like DropDownLists, etc that are placed all around like a common UI.

Comment: Do all of your filters have the same set of properties, or different ones?

Comment: Different. And that's why I will show the right controls first. Personally I wouldn't do it like this, I would just create the controls dynamically, but the customers want the controls to be in different positions. So Sharpen and Blur UIs look different from each other even though they share some parameters.

Comment: Can you host WPF content within your application?

Comment: I guess so. But I am not experienced with wpf at all, so I figure this might drag me way down in time?

Btw are there any links that shows wpf binding so I can see how easy it actually makes what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is using Windows Forms, the most flexible option would probably be to just use the Windows Forms PropertyGrid directly.

You can do a lot of work to customize the look and feel of this.  See Getting the [Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) for details.

---

Edit:

If you want to have a very flexible, easy option, and WPF is an option (hosted within an ElementHost), you could consider using WPF.

With this, you could host a UserControl containing nothing but a resource dictionary and a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx).

You could then make a custom XAML file for each item you want to edit, and setup a data template in the resources specifying the mapping of which user control (xaml) to use for each element you want to edit.  You can then just set the element to the user control's "DataContext" in code, and it will automatically wire everything up and "just work".

Comment: Thanks Reed, will check it out.

Comment: There's a better tutorial at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PropertyGridInCSharp11302005004139AM/PropertyGridInCSharp.aspx

Comment: @Darwyn: That tutorial is on using it, but not necessarily on customizing HOW your class displays.  It covers a different subject than what I was after.